# How recode R ggplot stack bars into plotly code?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

There is a great example of R ggplot code

```
    library(ggplot2)
 
    # create a dataset
    specie <- c(rep("sorgho" , 3) , rep("poacee" , 3) , rep("banana" , 3) , rep("triticum" , 3) )
    condition <- rep(c("normal" , "stress" , "Nitrogen") , 4)
    value <- abs(rnorm(12 , 0 , 15))
    data <- data.frame(specie,condition,value)
 
   # Stacked
   ggplot(data, aes(fill=condition, y=value, x=specie)) + 
    geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")
```

How to get the same in R 'plotly' format?

Answer (score 0):

It's easy with to make R plotly code

```
plot_ly(data, x = ~specie, y = ~value, color = ~condition, type = 'bar', name = ~condition) %>%
  layout(barmode = 'stack')
```

Answer (score -1):

a quick and easy way with the ggplotly() function from plotly package:
library(ggplot2)

```
# create a dataset
specie <- c(rep("sorgho" , 3) , rep("poacee" , 3) , rep("banana" , 3) , rep("triticum" , 3) )
condition <- rep(c("normal" , "stress" , "Nitrogen") , 4)
value <- abs(rnorm(12 , 0 , 15))
data <- data.frame(specie,condition,value)

# Stacked
my_plot <- ggplot(data, aes(fill=condition, y=value, x=specie)) + 
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")

# install.packages('plotly')
library(plotly)
ggplotly(my_plot)
```